# How to fingerprint with a removed field?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I want to put a field in a @metadata variable and use this field for fingerprinting later in logstash conf file. Is it possible for me to do this?Does anyone have an idea?
I made some attempts but no results. :

```
Filter{   
    csv{        
        autodetect_column_names => "true"
        separator => ","
        skip_header => "true"
        columns => ["name","surname","age","email","phone"]
    }
    mutate { 
          add_field => ["[@metadata][no_show]" => "%{[fields][name]}"]
          remove_field =>["name"]
    }
    fingerprint {
      method => "SHA1"
      source => [%{[@metadata][no_show]}]
      target => "fingerprint"
    } 
}
```

Comment: What does no results mean? Was there an error? What was the output event if there was no error?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a field called [fields][name], you have a field called [name], so change your mutate+add_field to refer to "%{[name]}".

Comment: I tried the way you said but it didn't work.

Comment: it doesn't give an error but it stays like this and doesn't progress. 

    [2021-10-07T11:57:04,804][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}